# Unreal Engine Pointers Issue (Not Understanding)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am a beginner to C++ and Unreal Engine, but I have been practicing. My issue is that I am having troubles with pointers in general, and not sure the point of using them over using an object... if that makes any sense. I know this question has most likely been answered, but I also have an issue in my code which I will attach. I'm not sure why, but the code does not compile unless I make it a pointer to my FString object... why does it not compile?

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.
#include "BullCowCartridge.h"

void UBullCowCartridge::BeginPlay() // When the game starts
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    SetupGame();
}

void UBullCowCartridge::OnInput(const FString& Input){ // When the player hits enter 
    ProcessGuess(Input);
}

void UBullCowCartridge::SetupGame() {
    //Establish HiddenWord
    HiddenWord = TEXT("minecraft");
    //Establish LifeCounter
    LifeCounter = HiddenWord.Len();
    //Establish GameOver
    bGameOver = false;

    //Print welcome screen/intro
    PrintLine(TEXT("WELCOME TO BULLS AND COWS!"));
    PrintLine(FString::Printf(TEXT("Guess the %i letter hidden word."), HiddenWord.Len()));
    PrintLine(FString::Printf(TEXT("Lives: %i"), LifeCounter));
    PrintLine(TEXT("\n"));
    PrintLine(TEXT("Enter your guess..."));
    PrintLine(TEXT(""));
}

void UBullCowCartridge::EndGame() {
    bGameOver = true;
    PrintLine(TEXT("Press enter to continue..."));
}

void UBullCowCartridge::ProcessGuess(FString Guess) {


    if (bGameOver) {
        ClearScreen();
        SetupGame();
        return;
    }

    if (Guess == HiddenWord) {
        ClearScreen();
        PrintLine(TEXT("You win!"));
        PrintLine(FString::Printf(TEXT("The hidden word was %s"), *HiddenWord));
        EndGame();
        return;
    }

    if (Guess.Len() != HiddenWord.Len()) {
        PrintLine(FString::Printf(TEXT("%i is not the correct amount of letters.\nPlease enter %i letters."), Guess.Len(), HiddenWord.Len()));
        return;
    }

    LifeCounter--;

    if (LifeCounter > 1) {
        PrintLine(FString::Printf(TEXT("You have %i lives remaining."), LifeCounter));
        return;
    }

    if (LifeCounter > 0) {
        PrintLine(FString::Printf(TEXT("You have %i life remaining."), LifeCounter));
        return;
    }
    else {
        ClearScreen();
        PrintLine(TEXT("You lose."));
        PrintLine(FString::Printf(TEXT("The hidden word was %s"), *HiddenWord));
        EndGame();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: For your general understanding of pointers there are more than enough resources on the internet.
What do you mean with "I'm not sure why, but the code does not compile unless I make it a pointer to my FString object" and which line?

Comment: I think you're referring to one of the UE_LOG calls? You're not actually getting a pointer to your string, you're using the * operator that is defined in FString, which returns its TCHAR representation, which is a TCHAR pointer.But the real problem here is that you should first learn C++ basics before you move to learning UE.

Comment: Please include the compilation failure message in your question.